# A word puzzle about complimenting one's appearance

Tags: word, wordplay

Think of a unit of measurement.

Now rearrange its letters and read them out loud to form a sentence (an example would be u r a b, meaning "You are a bee"). Make sure the sentence compliments someone on their appearance.

Now, what is the word? What is the sentence?

Comment: @user1717828 The title does not show anything the orignal puzzle-question wasn't asking as well. I think it was a good and appropriate edit.  +1 actually.

Comment: Was the accepted answer your intended one, or where you thinking on something else? Just curious. I do think it (currently) *is* the best answer, though.

Comment: @BmyGuest it was the intended answer, although the second answer is pretty great as well.

Comment: In the interests of documenting a puzzle's author and earlier publication: this was an NPR Sunday Puzzle, published in the 12 June 2016 entry of Blaine's Puzzle Blog, where it is credited to Andrew Chaikin of San Francisco. http://puzzles.blainesville.com/2016/06/npr-sunday-puzzle-june-12-2016-c-d-b-d.html

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It could also be a

> quart

Because

> You are a cutie! (u r a q t)

Comment: Sometimes, a great answer redeems a dull riddle..

Comment: +1 I prefer this answer, since it describes appearance better than the other answer.

Comment: @Roland the riddle would be ok if not for the misleading title

Comment: If this is the right answer, I think the question needs reworked - I got this answer immediately, in part because the sentence only differs from the example by one "word".

Answer (score 66):

Yet another possibility is

> Furlong

Which becomes

> fnlurog
>
> Pronounced "effin' 'ell, you are O.G.!"
>
> Wikipedia says that O.G., or [original gangster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_gangster):
> 'may refer to an individual (regardless of criminal affiliation) who represents ideals the speaker sees as Gangster and generally "tough" or "hood" in behavior and/or **looks** as well as a connection to the past or being older; commonly used as a **sign of respect**.'.

Comment: Up voting this because it is most certainly not what the OP had in mind :-)

Answer (score 34):

the unit could be

> The Lux, [the SI unit of illuminance and luminous emittance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux)
>  and the sentence "U X L" (You excel)

Comment: that was fast..did you already know the answer to that?

Comment: No, it's just the first unit with a "U" that have crossed my mind

Comment: I'm enjoying the irony of someone called "Lord of dark" coming up with this particular answer, but how is this a compliment on the hearer's *appearance* specifically?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'm not sure, I guess you can excel physically. But the "quart" answer in way better anyway ;)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Guess what: the first part of your comment is what attracts upvotes!!!

Answer (score 25):

It could also be

> cubit

which becomes

> i c b u t (I see beauty)

Comment: Or, `icubt`, I see you, beauty

Comment: Not "I see butt?"

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ -- wouldn't that be "I see you, beety"?

Comment: @BenM Say it with an Australian accent?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ - yeah, no. We still pronounce B as "Bee"

Answer (score -2):

it could also be

> **mole** (it is the unit of measurement for amount of substance)

because

> and the sentence is "M L E O"(AM LEO)